# Actionscript HsvToRgb not work with white

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert rgb to hsv in as3. I've a function that seems work well except with white color (255,255,255)

This is my function:

```
        public function RgbToHsv(red:Number, grn:Number, blu:Number):Object
    {
        var x, val, f, i, hue, sat, val;
        red/=255;
        grn/=255;
        blu/=255;
        x = Math.min(Math.min(red, grn), blu);
        val = Math.max(Math.max(red, grn), blu);
        if (x==val){
            return({h:undefined, s:0, v:val*100});
        }
        f = (red == x) ? grn-blu : ((grn == x) ? blu-red : red-grn);
        i = (red == x) ? 3 : ((grn == x) ? 5 : 1);
        hue = Math.floor((i-f/(val-x))*60)%360;
        sat = Math.floor(((val-x)/val)*100);
        val = Math.floor(val*100);
        return({h:hue, s:sat, v:val});
    }
```

The problem is that when I pass white rgb (255,255,255) I get this: h:null,s:0,v:100

Comment: Maybe you should try to type your variables to `Number` instead of letting Flash badly doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. Josh give a good point of view, so I simply changed this line:

```
if (x==val){
    return({h:undefined, s:0, v:val*100});
}
```

to

```
if (x==val){
    return({h:0, s:0, v:val*100});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing by zero for hue when the value is white.

```
val = Math.max(Math.max(red, grn), blu) = Math.max( Math.max( 255, 255 ), 255 ) = 255;
x = Math.min(Math.min(red, grn), blu) = Math.min(Math.min(255, 255), 255) = 255;
val - x = 255 - 255 = 0;
hue = Math.floor(( i - f / ( val - x )) * 60) % 360;
```

`x / 0` in AS3 (and most languages) is `NaN` (or null in this case because you are not typing your objects. AS3 is a **strict datatype** language. Every object **must** be typed).

I'm not sure how to fix the problem as I have not had to work with color theory or color algorithms in 18 months, but that is definitely the issue. Hue will actually be `NaN`/`null` every time you have a color with equal parts red, green, and blue for this reason (so not just white. Any grayscale color should result in the same issue)

Comment: You're right. the problem is the division. Probably I should first check if is 0 and then make division...

Comment: That would probably be the route to go. Is that the proper conversion? It seems odd that the standard conversion could lead to a division by 0.

Comment: I found this script on a forum I don't rememebr. I really don't know anything about color theory